# Can't execute ls using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to parse vsftpd logs to do some extra processing on the successfully uploaded files.

`username` will be the user so I create the home dir
`filename` is the file name in the log: it gives a wonky result i.e. "/foo.txt" but that doesn't matter

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo tail -F /var/log/vsftpd.log | while read line; do
  if sudo echo "$line" | grep -q 'OK UPLOAD:'; then
    username=$(echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f8 | sed 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\1/')
    filename=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f2 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//')
    home="/home/vsftpd/$username"
    if sudo ls "$home$filename" &> /dev/null; then
      # do something with $filename
        echo "some text"
    fi
  fi
done
```

When a file is uploaded I expect the text "some text". I never get that instead I can see it reports:

`ls: cannot access /home/vsftpd/user1"/foo.txt": No such file or directory`

Although I can run the command in the shell:

```
$ sudo ls /home/vsftpd/user1"/foo.txt"
/home/vsftpd/user1/foo.txt
```

I'm guessing permissions related but I've got it running as sudo and I've given the directories full access. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have an extra set of quotes around the file name component that you need to strip.  The file name in the vsftpd logs (just verified this for myself) is surrounded with quotes, and unlike with username you're not removing those quotes.

This means that `$filename` ends up being set to, literally, `"/foo.txt"` including the quotes.  When you construct the file name for `ls` with `"$home$filename"`, the variables are interpolated, but the shell isn't then going to strip off *another* level of quotes.  The quotes stay in the final file name, and the directory `/home/vsftpd/user1"` with the trailing quote doesn't exist.

This works when you enter the command from the shell because you aren't quoting the file name, so the shell does *another* round of quote interpolation and removes the double quotes.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for looking deeper into the vsftpd logs. I just fixed it with this line: `filename=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f2 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | tr -d '"')`

Answer (score 0):

If sudo works from the shell, it's possible that sudo has the `NOEXEC` flag set, which prevents it from executing scripts. You can read more about `NOEXEC` [here](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html).